# The difference between static scope and dynamic scope

Tags: scope, lexical-scope, dynamic-scope

My teacher has provided the following pseudo-code, and says that the output using static scope is `1 2 3`, but the output using dynamic scope is `2 3 4`.

The Challenge is in Static Scope we use a=1, b=2, c=3 without attention to main or no, use  a=1, b=2, c=4? Just in Static Scope without including C Rules.

```
void fun1(void);
void fun2(void);

int a=1, b=2, c=3;

int main() {
    c=4;
    fun1();
    return 0;
}

void fun1() {
    int a=2, b=3;
    fun2();
}

void fun2(){
    printf("%d%d%d", a,b,c);
}
```

Comment: You may have misinterpreted what your teacher says. In C, this code can only give one output: `124`.

Comment: The interesting thing is that the code doesn't output `1 2 3` or `2 3 4`. So maybe the first step to understanding the code is to actually run the code and see what it outputs.

Comment: You need to explain (demonstrate) how the scope is changed between 'static' and 'dynamic'.  As written, the code can only produce one answer — and that's `124`.  Note that printing operations should generally end with a newline, too — that's sloppy style on display.  You could get `123` if the reference to `c` in `main()` was prefixed with `int`; you could get `234` if the references to `a` and `b` in `fun1()` were not prefixed with `int`.

Comment: @kaylum dynamic and static scope is differ.

Comment: Sorry, that statement does not make sense in the context of the code shown and the question you asked. What do you understand to be dynamic and static scope in C? And how can that possibly affect the output of the code *as shown*? Or are you asking how can the code be changed to produce the different suggested outputs?

Comment: @MaryamPanahi: How are the dynamic and static scopes different?  What changes in the code between the two?  It isn't standard C terminology, which is one reason why there is confusion.  The words 'dynamic', 'static' and 'scope' are used individually, but not usually as 'dynamic scope' or as 'static scope'.

Comment: You need to answer, or ask the teacher, what on earth is meant by 'dynamic scope' here. It is meaningless to me in the context of this code, and I'm both a compiler writer and a 30+-year user of C. Either you or he is misusing standard terminology. All the scopes shown here are static. The first declaration of `a,b,c` has static *linkage*, and the other declarations have automatic *allocation.*

Comment: @EJP maybe means of my teacher is simulating dynamic scope on pesuedocode like C ?

Comment: @MaryamPanahi Maybe anything. With the information you've provided it is impossible to say, and speculating about it is pointless. You've tagged the question as C, and in C all the above comments apply, except yours: there is no such thing as dynamic scope, and this code does not produce either of the outputs claimed.

Comment: Duplicate of [Lexical scoping vs dynamic in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19574605/207421).

Comment: @EJP my last question is in static scope the result is 1 2 4 surely without any assumption. am I right?

Comment: @EJP As "compiler writer" you should've heard of it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scoping

Comment: @DanielJour Read what I wrote. I chose my words with care. I didn't say I'd never heard of it. I said it is 'meaningless to me in the context of this code'.

Comment: @EJP Ah ... expanding the comments shows the link you posted. I just wanted to share the information with you in case you (as I presumed) didn't know about it. (One can have a lot of fun with dynamic scope .. retro fitting a condition system, for example) I hope I didn't sounded offensive (if so I'm sorry, my comment wasn't meant to be offensive)

Comment: The primary problem was that the question was tagged [tag:c] but it makes no sense as C.  The problem was then compounded when someone removed the tags about [tag:compiler-construction] and [tag:programming-languages].  Now that it is not tagged [tag:c], it makes more sense, though using C functions such as `printf()` still has the potential to cause some confusion.  In this context, using some pseudo-language construct (e.g. `print a, b, c;`) along with an explanation that this is _not_ C code would have stopped people going down the wrong path.  The comments above a mainly appropriate for C.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler there is one problem I think... In static scope the fun2fun2 takes the globally scoped cc which comes from scope where function is defined (opposite to dynamic, where it traverses scopes of execution), so c=3 not c=4 !

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52990/755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* dynamic scope were possible in C, then lookup of the variables `a`, `b` and `c` inside of `fun2` would use the dynamic environment.

This, in turn, depends on how the function got actually called. Since it's called from `fun1` the variable bindings of that scope will be used (thus `a = 2` and `b = 3`). Because `fun1` had been called from `main`, which set up the binding `c = 4`, the output would be `2 3 4`.

---

Another example:

```
void fun1(void);
void fun2(void);
void fun3(void);

int a=1, b=2, c=3;

int main()
{
    c=4;
    fun1();
    int a = 21;
    fun3();
    return 0;
}

void fun1()
{
    int a=2, b=3;
    fun2();
}

void fun2()
{
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a,b,c);
}

void fun3() {
  int c = 42;
  fun2();
}
```

*Would* print

```
2 3 4
21 2 42
```

---

Perhaps actually seeing the difference helps you. Clojure supports both dynamic and lexical scoping (this is the correct terminology, btw):

```clj
(def static-scoped 21)
(def ^:dynamic dynamic-scoped 21)

(defn some-function []
  (println "static = " static-scoped)
  (println "dynamic = " dynamic-scoped))

(defn other-function []
  (binding [dynamic-scoped 42]
    (println "Established new binding in dynamic environment")
    (some-function)))

;; Trying to establish a new binding for the static-scoped
;; variable won t affect the function defined
;; above.
(let [static-scoped 42]
  (println "This binding won't affect the variable resolution")
  (other-function))

(println "calling some-function directly")
(some-function)
```

[(live)](http://ideone.com/PgiMlU)

Note that Clojure tries to be as purely functional as possible, thus none of the code above is a assignment (in other words: the values of the variables aren't modified once assigned)

Comment: @user3386109 The question is tagged with compiler construction and programming languages. I'd guess this is from a compiler / programming languages class, possibly using a subset of C as language for some experiments.

Comment: @DanielJour you are correct from the Programm Lang.. Class.

Comment: Indeed. It's a "what if C had.." type of question.

Comment: would you please more inspect on Static and Dynamic Differ in your answer?

Comment: One depends on the (static) location in the source code, the other on the (dynamic) history that got you were you are during runtime. You'd need to be a bit more precise about what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: How we reach to  1 2 3 ?

Comment: 1 2 3 will be the result (if you change the line in `main` from `c = 4` to `int c = 4`) under static scope because variable lookup then only uses syntactically higher levels. That's: if no binding for `a` is found in the current scope it'll look in the containing scope, which is the global scope with `a = 1` in your example)

Comment: You means in static just use the higher level definition ?

Comment: There is something Wrong ! I get 1 2 4 not 1 2 3.

Comment: Please *read all* of my comment: "[..] (if you change the line in main from `c = 4` to `int c = 4`) [..]"

Comment: I Get it. I think in Static Rule we dont enter in main() and use a=1,b=2,c=3, but if we use C Rules , 1 2 4.

Comment: No. Without the above change it's never `1 2 3` because you *change* the global `a` to `4` inside of `main`.

Comment: Daneil as my last questions is it possible to implement it in pascal on online IDE to see the result?

Comment: I don't know (haven't done much with Pascal, and it's been a while) but probably not, because this is part of the fundamental machinery of a programming language and as such cannot be changed (without ugly hacks).

Comment: You could implement a simple Lisp and play with the different scoping models, though.

Comment: I want to test it in a another static scope language, just test. would you please help me now ?

Comment: In static scope the fun2fun2 takes the globally scoped cc which comes from scope where function is defined (opposite to dynamic, where it traverses scopes of execution), so c=3 !!

Comment: You seem to have a serious confusion between scope and actual execution path. With lexical scope it's `c = 4` because in main the `c` is resolved to the global one and then assigned that new value, overwriting the previously stored 3.

Comment: Is it possible to make it clear for me Daniel?